# Stencil: Rendering Dynamic Attributes in WebComponent

Tags: stenciljs

Implementing dynamic Attributes within a Tag seems not possible.
What i want to achieve is following:

I want to define my own select-component, render code as follows:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Host>
            <select class={this.cssClassMap} aria-label={this.label}>
                {
                    this.options.map((opt) => {
                        const Tag = 'option';
                        return <Tag value={this.extractValue(opt)}>{this.writeElement(opt, ['value'])}</Tag>;
                    })
                }
            </select>
        </Host>
    );
}
```

Whilist the const "Tag" can be defined dynamically as string i have no chance to render dynamically zero or more attributes, here in this example it's "value".

What i want to achieve is something like:

```
 this.options.map((opt) => {
                    const Tag = 'option';
                    return <Tag determineAttributeList(opt)>{this.writeElement(opt, ['value'])}</Tag>;
                })
```

I can't find anything on this.

Should be the latest stencil version Date 15.02.

Comment: Do you get an error message (on build or run)? Can you post the `determineAttributeList`  function?

Comment: determineAttributeList is just an synthetic example and does not exist, yet. i am not aware on how to add the attributes of a tag dynamically. they should be evalutated from the incoming element.
with the first snipped posted, i get no error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to dynamically add attributes/properties you can use an object and destructure it:

```
const determineAttributeList = (option) => {
  return {
    value: option.value,
    customAttr: option.custom,
  };
}

return (
  <select>
    {this.options.map((opt) => {
      const Tag = 'option';
      return <Tag {...determineAttributeList(opt)}>{this.writeElement(opt, ['value'])}</Tag>;
    })
  </select>
);
```

Note the `{... }` around the `determineAttributeList` function call.